# What is the difference between XML document & XML string?

Tags: javascript, xml

Is there any content difference between the data?

Perhaps a document may have additional metadata like author, last date edited, etc.?

I'm trying to understand why the domparser example at w3 schools has two completely different methods for loading an xml string vs an xml document.

For example say both sources contained `<book><page1>Hello World!</page1></book>`.

First method offered loads the js object xmlDoc using XMLHttpRequest() and responseXML, the second uses DOMParser() and parseFromString()

How would the JS objects created by each method differ from one another?

Comment: Yes, @Philipp, I have some issues with some of their content (and was smart enough to research that their certs are expensive paper), but I still find a lot of it useful and informative. Could you recommend a better alternative?

Comment: @Medicdude https://developer.mozilla.org

Comment: @PeeHaa thankyou, I was actually looking at their canvas tutorials the other day, I didn't even realize there was a whole site there.

Comment: @Philipp: While your statement is true you shouldn't just post a link to this site. If you do so always mention *why* w3schools is bad and should not be linked.

Comment: Ah yes, thankyou, I didn't even realize that XD (removed). I suppose having erroneous content gets them more links then having correct content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of both ways is an object representing a xml structure.

The first way is loading (and parsing) a xml document from a remote location using an XMLHttpRequest.

The second way assumes you already have xml content in your script (stored in a variable, doesn't matter how it got there). The xml string content will then be parsed to an object so you can easily perform operations on the xml data (which isn't possible on the string)

You can work with the resulting xml object like this:

```
var p = new DOMParser()
xmldoc = p.parseFromString('<book><page1>Hello World!</page1></book>', 'text/xml')

xmldoc.childNodes.item(0) // the <book> tag
xmldoc.childNodes.item(0).childNodes.item(0) // the <page1> tag
xmldoc.childNodes.item(0).childNodes.item(0).textContent // "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Ok, assuming both sources had the same xml content (say <book><page1>Hello World</page1></book>) , would the js objects created by each method be the same?

Comment: The result should be the same. First way: `request returns xml as text data -> parsing xml -> xml document is returned`. Second way `string variable containing xml content -> parsing xml -> xml document is returned`.

Comment: Ok, so the xml document is just a javascript object I can then traverse through? So if I wanted to get the text, could I go xmlDoc.book.page1.getText()?

Comment: Not exactly. Updated the answer

Comment: Ok, could you also use 'xmldoc.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].textContent' ?

Answer (score 0):

The first example builds an XML tree from an XML file you still have to load. It uses the XMLHttpRequest for that, which loads an XML file from a webserver and automatically parses it to create an XML document.

The second example builds an XML tree from a string you already have which contains XML code.

Comment: When you say 'builds an XML tree' what does that mean. Does it create a javascript object that resembles the xml document?

Answer (score 0):

xml documents should begin with an xml declaration:

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd

This declaration might not be present in the xml string.