# Difference between XMLDOM document, XML document and XML String document

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

Can any one tell me what is XML String document and XMLDOM document? What will be the extension of those two documents (XML String and XMLDOM). How does those document differ from normal XML Document(.xml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLDOM document (which is actually XML DOM) or **XML Document Object Model** is an in-memory representation of an XML document. The DOM allows you to read, write, replace, manipulate and copy a XML document via code. For further reading, take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9hbf87(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757022(v=vs.85).aspx).

Never heard of XML String document, but i geuss you mean the type that represents the text written inside the XML document. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007488/what-is-the-difference-between-xml-document-xml-string?rq=1) for more information.

Comment: What will be the extension of XML DOM document. Do we have seperate extension or it comes by .xml extension only?

Comment: XML DOM - The D is document, so don't add the document after you say XML DOM :)...The DOM is just a class...It's a way to represent a "normal" XML document.